# How to override Rails ActiveRecord insert primary key method?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to insert a primary key named `identity` for multiple micro-services record tracking.

And the `identity` column's rule is:

> service_name.to_i(36) + '-' + table_name.to_i(36) + id.to_s(36)

And I want to achieve three thing:

1. Uniqueness
2. Table primary key
3. `identity` can be decode to get the information

I do a lot of research for 'How to get id before/around create', but I can't find the good answer.

I already tried:

1. ActiveRecord Callback: around_save, around_create
2. Insert `identity` in after_create, but it's not a good solution because the performance issue
3. Get id via `self.class.maximum(:id) + 1`
4. Get id via mysql `LAST_INSERT_ID()`

So, now I want to add `identity` ActiveRecord source where it insert primary key `id` to override, but I don't know where rails deal the primary key around insert.

Please help, thanks!

Comment: Did you consider [a custom autoincrement function](http://en.latindevelopers.com/ivancp/2012/custom-auto-increment-values/)?

Comment: @spickermann this can seem to solve my question, I will try it, thank you!